# How should I redirect users based on role if there are 100s of roles?

Tags: webforms, redirection

I am creating an evaluation webform where students evaluate both instructor and lab location on the same form based on class section number.

**How do I redirect students to the correct form if there are 100s of sections?**

Writing conditional based logic on global $user and checking for roles seems trivial. Login Destination will do the trick, but not sure how to handle 100s roles.

**EDIT:** The url structure would something along the lines of:

`class/section/instructor` or `class/section/lab`

**Caveats:** One instructor could belong to many sections since they can teach any number of classes.

**Edit #2** Main entities/fields on the form are:

Instructor: can belong to many classes and sections

Class Name: i.e. Industrial Economy. A single class can have many sections (or units in laymen's term).

Section: belongs to a single class.

Class Number: Classnumber-followed by section number ie. ABC23343-34 (the last two digits are class section).

**Key identifier and workflows:**

Once a student logs in, he/she should see the list of classes they belongs to and fill out the evaluation form for that section. Essentially, a single student could have 5 or 6 forms. **Apologies!** this changes the question a bit. Actual form content stays the same (so a single form could be used as a template to attach to many entities).

Comment: Why do you have 100 forms? Why not just one form with maybe conditional fields? wouldn't having all data together make it easier to process it later? I believe problems like this indicate there might be serious design mistake earlier.

Comment: You may be right in terms design flaw. But we want each instructor to be able to access the evaluation results later. Thus the individual forms...

Comment: Taxonomy might be the solution instead of "roles". Add the taxonomy to the user entity as well as the webform (node) entity. Then you can associate the two, and use some smart redirecting based on taxonomy. I guess the vocab would be "instructor" and each instructor's name is a term in that vocab. So then a form, and a user (student) each belong to an instructor, therefore you have your connection.

Comment: You can even use [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module to restrict access to each form if you want to take it a step further.

Comment: @JT-Drupal To be honest, I'd go with my own custom module here. But if Views support for Webform results is finally working as it should, I'd consider using one form and contextual filter on results to provide review limitations.

Comment: @Beebee - thanks. I did not think about it at all. This might work.

Comment: @Mołot - if all else fails, that's' the route I will go with. Feeling a little bit lazy where there is tons of modules I can build with. Just got to find the correct ones.

Comment: Can you EDIT your question to explain how your URL structure looks like. If you have 100s of something, I'm assuming you can somehow use a parm, destination, etc in your URL, no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - just updated the question

Comment: OK, that helps a bit already. Few more (new) questions (please  edit answer to clarify): (a) can you give 2 or 3 examples (I assume the 'section' is actually a number or something, and 'instructior' is some userid, name or someting (b) what actually is a "section" (sorry if this is a strange question, I'm not native English ...). After you clarify these extra questions, I might post an answer with an actual solution I'm thinking of ...

Comment: Thanks @Pierre.Vriens! I just added some extra information, which changes the question a bit. Now redirection is not required... Your assumptions are correct.